# select a row from a flextable in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google script. I have a datasource that I need to display in a table and allow user to select a row and select open button. the event handler of the open button should be able to find out the row number so that I will be able to send a  request with the name user chosen.

I thought of adding a check box and on the click event, simply read the name of the checkbox which has the row number.

Please let me know how to do this. thanks

```
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 300);
   scroll.add(panel);

   var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '1px solid black')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(1); 
   flexTable.setText(0, 1, 'Application Name')
   flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(0,'color', 'blue')
   flexTable.setText(0, 2, 'Owner')
   flexTable.setText(0, 3, 'Date')

   var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('clickTable');
   var counter = 1;
   for (var i in queryResult.records) {
      var chkBox = app.createCheckBox().setName('chk' + counter).setId('chk');

      var owner  = queryResult.records[i]["Owner"]["Name"];
      var AppName = queryResult.records[i]["Name"];
      var ModifiedDate =  queryResult.records[i]["LastModifiedDate"]
      var UniqId =  queryResult.records[i]["Apttus_XApps__UniqueId__c"]
      flexTable.setWidget(counter, 0 , chkBox)
      flexTable.setText(counter, 1, AppName.toString());
      flexTable.setText(counter, 2, owner.toString());
      flexTable.setText(counter, 3, ModifiedDate.toString());
      counter ++; 
    }

  panel.add(app.createButton('Open', handler));
  panel.add(flexTable);
  app.add(scroll);
```

Comment: your code seems right... what is the problem ?

Comment: The only feature I would personally add is to prevent clicking the button until a check box is selected...or, if only one can be selected use radioButtons because these are "exclusive". What do you think?

Comment: Serge has it right, you need to use RadioButton controls so that the user can only select one record at a time. Also, you need to apply the same counter to the control Id - and personally, I would delimit the name/Id using an underscore so that you can easily split the index from the class in your handler:
var chkBox = app.createCheckBox().setName('chk_' + counter).setId('chk_' + counter)
Note that the RadioButton has a different naming convention for grouped controls, so check the documentation

Comment: @Tim : thx, finally I posted a full code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have only created server handler, but no callback elements are attached to it. Please have a look at this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler#addCallbackElement(Widget))

So your code will be like.

```
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('clickTable');
handler.addCallbackElement(panel)
```

Next: at your server function clickTable

```
function clickTable(e)
{
for (var i in e.parameter) {
   Logger.log('parameter ' + i+1 + ' is ' + e.parameter[i]);
  }
```

//try logging all the values that are passed and use it accordingly, 
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an implementation I suggested in comments above using radioButtons.

User can only submit if one option has been selected

[test online here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7TVqhh6T7VHw9iqorFRxTEomcmD-GzUammrpTJc9WlXTyfLD9/exec)

code :

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'padding':'15px'});
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('clickTable').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var btn = app.createButton('Open', handler).setEnabled(false);
  panel.add(btn);
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);
  scroll.add(panel);
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '1px solid black')
  .setStyleAttributes({'borderCollapse':'collapse'})
  .setBorderWidth(1).setCellPadding(2); 
  flexTable.setText(0, 1, 'Application Name')
  flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(0,'color', 'blue')
  flexTable.setText(0, 2, 'Owner')
  flexTable.setText(0, 3, 'Date')
  var radioValue = app.createTextBox().setName('radioValue').setVisible(false);// set it to visible if you want to see what happens in tests
  panel.add(radioValue);  
  var counter = 1;
  for (var i =0;i<10;i++) {
    var name = counter;
    var radio = app.createRadioButton('radioBtn','select');
    var CliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(radioValue).setText(name).forTargets(btn).setEnabled(true);
    radio.addClickHandler(CliHandler);
//    var owner  = queryResult.records[i]["Owner"]["Name"];
//    var AppName = queryResult.records[i]["Name"];
//    var ModifiedDate =  queryResult.records[i]["LastModifiedDate"]
//    var UniqId =  queryResult.records[i]["Apttus_XApps__UniqueId__c"]
//  temp var definitions for test
var owner  = 'test';
var AppName = 'test';
var ModifiedDate =  'test';
var UniqId =  'test';
// delete in production code
    flexTable.setWidget(counter, 0 , radio)
    flexTable.setText(counter, 1, AppName.toString());
    flexTable.setText(counter, 2, owner.toString());
    flexTable.setText(counter, 3, ModifiedDate.toString());
    counter ++; 
  }

  panel.add(flexTable);
  app.add(scroll);
  return app;
}

function clickTable(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel('you have selected item nr '+e.parameter.radioValue));
  return app
}
```

Comment: interesting approach, not using an Id - guess it gets the job done, but for an OO developer, this took a few tries to figure out! :))
I will have to remember that technique though

Comment: This is the only way to get radioButtons working with the same name when they are not the source of the server handler(the button in this example) their id are not returned in the callbackElement and they all have the same name so it's a "no way". This solution with client handlers was originally suggested by Romain Vialard, another TC on the old Google forum (now wiped out) about 3 years ago... That's an old one isn't it ? :-)